# For loops iteration in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve the following simple problem in matlab:
[image]

I am trying to do this by using for loops. However, I havent quite figured it out.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
n = [0:1:10];
b = 2*n;
c = 0.5*n;

B=0;
for ii = 1:length(b)
    for jj = 1:length(c)
         B(ii) = B+sum(b(jj)*c(ii-jj))
     end
end
```

It seems like I come into a problem when ii=jj and I have c(0), and this index cannot be used.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab indexes arrays from `1`, so the element `c(0)` does not exist. The easiest way to fix this would be to add `1` to your expression, so probably

```
B(ii) = B+sum(b(jj)*c(ii-jj+1))
```

but do check that this doesn't give you an off-by-1 error at the other end of the vector.

In general, since Matlab does index from 1, you need to take account of this when translating algorithms from sources, such as your mathematical expression, which index from 0.  This is the sort of adjustment one has to make when writing software.

EDIT: as @Dan has commented, you should also revise the loop over `jj` to `for jj = 1:ii`.

Comment: You can also leave off the `sum` since it will only ever be summing a single number

Comment: Well, yes indeed, but I was answering the question, not providing a code improvement service. In that latter sense either your answer or @RobertP's is better than mine, but mine does explain why `c(0)` can't be used.

Comment: I agree, it is the best answer. But I think to be fully correct you should also note the error in `for jj = 1:length(c)` as it should be `for jj = 1:ii`. The `sum` thing is just an extra. But +1 anyways for explaining the error

Answer (score 7):

You are just doing a convolution:

```
B = conv(b,c);
B = B(1:numel(b)); %// remove unwanted values
```

Answer (score 1):

So you need to put a logic as if (ii==jj) B(ii) = B+sum(b(jj)*c(ii-jj+1)) Else B(ii) = B+sum(b(jj)*c(ii-jj)) This is a pseudo code so you can have this logic converted.

Comment: This is not an answer, but rather a comment. Hence i flagged it to be changed into a comment.

Comment: This is not an answer, you should delete it and re-post as a comment on the question

Comment: So you need to put a logic as 
if (ii==jj)
   B(ii) = B+sum(b(jj)*c(ii-jj+1))
Else
B(ii) = B+sum(b(jj)*c(ii-jj))

This is a pseudo code so you can have this logic converted.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I dont have the privelages to comment. Thanks

Comment: @RamMehta: there are SO reasons that you don't have the privilege to comment.  So don't comment, work hard at improving your rep so that you acquire the privilege.  But posting non-answers will, as you see, only damage your rep.

Answer (score 1):

```
N = 1:10;
b = 2*N;
c = 0.5*N;

B=zeros(length(N),1);  %//This preallocation of B makes your code much faster

for n = N
    for k = 1:n %//Note the change here
         B(n) = B(n) + b(k)*c(n-k+1);  %// Added the +1 to the index of c like High Performance Mark suggests but also note you don't need the sum() since b(k)*c(n-k+1) is only a single number anyways
    end
end
```

or even better you can vectorize the inner loop:

```
for n = N
    B2(n) = b(1:n)*c(n:-1:1)';
end
```